# how to convert dictionary with list to list of dictionary with unequal no of values for each associated keys in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to convert

```
data_table = {"Red":[1,2,3], "Blue":[4,5,6]}
```

To

```
data_table = [ {"Red": 1, "Blue": 4 }, {"Red": 2, "Blue": 5}, {"Red": 3, "Blue": 6}]
```

One possible approach is to use pandas data frame. There might be cases where our dictionary has more than 100's of keys in it.

```
import pandas as pd
df =  pd.DataFrame(data_table, index=['row1', 'row2', 'row3'])
print(df.to_dict('records'))
```

What I really wanted to know if the keys in `data_table` have unequal no of values in them. In the following example 'Black' has 2 values in the list, whereas all other keys in the dictionary have 3 values associated with it.

```
data_new = {'Red': [1,2,3], 'Blue': [4,5,6], 'Green': [7,8,9], 'Black': [0,10]}
```

to

```
data_new = [{'Red': 1, 'Blue':4,'Green':7, 'Black':0}, {'Red': 2, 'Blue':5,'Green': 8,'Black': 10}, {'Red': 3, 'Blue': 6, 'Green':9}]
```

Pandas dataFrame approach fails as it can't broadcast.

Any possible approach would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Approach 1 (without `pandas`)

We can zip the values in dictionary using `zip_longest` from `itertools`, then iterate over the zipped values inside a list comprehension and for each zipped value create the records inside a dict comprehension

```
from itertools import zip_longest

[{k:v for k, v in zip(data_new.keys(), vals) if v is not None}
                  for vals in zip_longest(*data_new.values())]
```

#### Approach 2 (with `pandas`)

We can create a new dataframe with orientation set to index from the given dictionary, then stack the dataframe to reshape followed by groupby on level=1 and map each to dict inside a list comprehension

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_new, 'index').stack().astype(int)

i = df.index.get_level_values(1)
[dict(g) for _, g in df.droplevel(1).groupby(i)]
```

#### Result

```
[{'Red': 1, 'Blue': 4, 'Green': 7, 'Black': 0},
 {'Red': 2, 'Blue': 5, 'Green': 8, 'Black': 10},
 {'Red': 3, 'Blue': 6, 'Green': 9}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension

```
data_table = {"Red":[1,2,3], "Blue":[4,5,6]}
new = [{'Red':r,'Blue':b} for r,b in zip(data_table['Red'],data_table['Blue'])]
```

output

```
[{'Red': 1, 'Blue': 4}, {'Red': 2, 'Blue': 5}, {'Red': 3, 'Blue': 6}]
```

Comment: Thanks @BuddyBob!! , But if the dictionary is quite large how to approach it??

Comment: Like it has multiple keys?